# post content of xslt transformation in seperate divs with javascript function

Tags: javascript, xslt

I am trying to read through an xml file with xslt transformations and place the content into different divs. I am limited in some solutions in that I CANNOT use any server side languages this content will run local (direct from a cd) and must work in IE (i know why right?) per client specs

Essentially I would like to put all the phases in the "phase" div with an onClick function that loads the lessons into the "lessons" div

some of the code below is pseudo and does not function
thanks in advance for any assistance.

**XML File**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <menu frame="UH1Y" curriculum="Crew Chief Training ICW">
          <phase name='Unit 01'>
             <lesson link='lesson01/menu.htm'>lesson 01</lesson>
             <lesson link='lesson02/menu.htm'>lesson 02</lesson>
             <lesson link='lesson03/menu.htm'>lesson 03</lesson>
             <lesson link='lesson04/menu.htm'>lesson 04</lesson>
             <lesson link='lesson0/menu.htm'>lesson 05</lesson>
          </phase>
      <phase name='Unit 02'>
        <lesson link='lesson01/menu.htm'>lesson 01</lesson>
        <lesson link='lesson02/menu.htm'>lesson 02</lesson>
        <lesson link='lesson03/menu.htm'>lesson 03</lesson>
      </phase>
    </menu>
```

**XSL File**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>menu</title>
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="scripts/menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container2">
      <div id="phase">
        <ul>
          <xsl:for-each select="menu/phase">
            <li  onclick='loadLesson(<xsl:value-of select="menu/phase/@name[current()]"/>);'> 
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/></li>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="lesson2">
        <ul>
          <xsl:for-each select="menu/phase[position() = {*the current phase*]/lesson">
            <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**JS file**

```
function loadLesson(x) {
    alert(x);
    //<xsl:value-of select="menu/phase/@name[current()]"/>
    theDiv=document.getElementById('lesson2')
    theDiv.innerHTML = x;

}
```

Comment: It would help if you gave us an expected output. And what is your question, exactly? Are you wondering why that xsl doesn't work as you expect? Just glancing at the code, inside your for-each the XPath isn't correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than do another XSLT transform each time a user clicks a link, it might be worth simply rendering out all possible divs on the page in the first place, and making them all hidden (using the CSS display property). Then, when they select a 'phase' simply make the relevant div visible.

The first problem with your XSLT though is this

```
 <li onclick='loadLesson(<xsl:value-of select="menu/phase/@name[current()]"/>);'>
```

It is not valid to have XSLT elements embedded in an attribute like this. In this case, you would really need to use "Attribute Value Templates". Also note as you are already positioned on a **phase** element, you don't need to write the full path here, just **@name** would do.

```
 <li onclick="loadLesson('{@name}');'>
```

Note the curly braces here, as this indicates the Attribute Value Template, and the contents of the braces are evaluated, rather than output literally.

Actually, because you are going to have a separate div for each phase, each such div would need a unique Id, one without spaces in, so it might be better to do this

```
<li onclick="loadLesson('phase_{generate-id()}');">
```

Then to render out the lessons for each phase, you could do this

```
  <xsl:for-each select="menu/phase">
  <div id="phase_{generate-id()}" style="display:none">
    <ul>
      <xsl:for-each select="lesson">
        <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Again note the use of Attribute Value Templates to set the Id of the div.

Then, finally, you would write your javascript function **loadLesson** like so:

```
var current_div = null;
function loadLesson(divId)
{
   if (current_div != null) current_div.style.display = 'none';

   current_div = document.getElementById(divId);
   current_div.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Here is the full XSLT in this case:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>menu</title>
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="scripts/menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container2">
      <div id="phase">
        <ul>
          <xsl:for-each select="menu/phase">
            <li onclick="loadLesson('phase_{generate-id()}');"> 
               <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            </li>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <xsl:for-each select="menu/phase">
      <div id="phase_{generate-id()}" style="display:none">
        <ul>
          <xsl:for-each select="lesson">
            <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation. I will work on it now and let you know how it works out.

Comment: Amazing work Tim,exactly what i needed, you did more of the work than i expected all i had to do was copy and paste. now i just have to add the links to the lessons and it is finished. thanks for the help. +10